# Adding a column to an imported spreadsheet - PHPmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've imported data to phpmyadmin and I need to add a column to create a primary key (called companyID) How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can select your database table in PHPMyAdmin.

From here you will have the option above beside 'Browse' called 'Structure'.

Once in 'Structure' view, down below the column listing you will see Add [ 1 ] (textbox) column(s) with three radio button options: At End of Table, At Beginning of Table, and After [ column names select box] with 'Go'.

You'll want to add 1 column and use 'Go' which will allow you to set the additional column up manually.